# saber si ya pasaros 3 meses con js

Tags: javascript, date, variables, function

¿como saber si han pasado 3 meses en js?

```
var mes_ini=10;
var mes=new Date().getMonth();
var ano=new Date().getFullYear();
var plan=leercookie("plan");
    var mes3=mes_ini+3;
    if (mes <= mes3) {
    a("no pasaron 3 meses");
    }else{
    //han pasado 3 meses
    }
```

¿de esa manera es correcta?

Comment: Ummm es cierto que tienes codigo por lo tanto la pregunta deberia ser valida, y pues... yo la considero valida, pero amigo, ten en cuenta que el objeto `Date`, no te va a servir **de manera directa** para lo que necesitas, yo lo que te aconsejo es que en este caso uses `cookies` ya que las `cookies` lo bueno de ellas es que tienen un tiempo de vida que les puedes especificar en este caso 3 meses. asi que te aconsejo investigar sobre las `cookies` en javascript, despues de ello simplemente creas la cookie con el tiempo especificado y cada vez que el usuario acceda a la pagina

Comment: Simplemente haces que el codigo compruebe si la `cookie` aun existe, si la cookie ya no existe entonces quiere decir que han pasado 3 meses. tambien debes de mirar si la `cookie` ya no ha sido creada antes de crearla porque de lo contrario estaras sobreescribiendo el tiempo de la `cookie`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función pasando por parámetro objetos `Date` de JavaScript:

```js
function monthDiff(date1, date2) { // date1 and date2 are Date() objects
    var months;
    months = (date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= date1.getMonth();
    months += date2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

De forma en que, cuando necesitas saberla diferencia entre dos fechas, hagas esto:

```js
function someFunction() {
    var getted_date = Date.parse('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var today_date = Date.now();

    var diff = monthDiff(today_date, getted_date);

    if(diff >= 3) {
        // Already 3 moths
    } else {
        // Not 3 moths yet
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que el usuario se refiere a que quiere contar el tiempo desde una sesion `X` hasta que hayan pasado literalmente 3 meses en la vida real, esto no recordaria ese tiempo.

Comment: Tu función tiene un problema y es que no calcula realmente la diferencia exacta en meses. Si paso como argumentos a tu función los siguientes objetos: `new Date('2020-01-31')` y `new Date('2020-04-01')`, me devuelve `3`. Si bien una fecha es de enero y la otra de abril, no han pasado 3 meses exactos, realmente han pasado: el último día de enero más los 29 días de febrero más los 31 días de marzo más el primer día de abril, lo cual suma 62 días. 3 meses exactos son (en promedio) 90 días. Verifica tu respuesta. Saludos.